# AppsScript- Using an image from Google Drive in HtmlService

Tags: html, image, google-apps-script

The Images section of the following document

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/html_service

says that only images hosted on a public url can be displayed (due to the use of the image proxy).

Does that apply to images stored in the user's google drive?
Is there any way to use such images as HtmlService elements?

Comment: You can create [google blog](https://www.blogger.com) , insert image in it , copy image link and use it in your google app script :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is not yet a way to do what you are asking.

Comment: Once again thanks for the clear answer. Do you know if there are plans to support this? Seems kind of strange to have Drive and not being able to use it in HtmlOutput.

Comment: I can't promise anything, but it's definitely a use case we are aware of and are looking at.

Comment: The restriction is actually lifted now. You can use https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=<FILE_ID> to link to a private image on Google Drive. But the authorization is kind of strange. I had both development Google account and my personal Google account which has no privilege to the App as well as the image logged in. The Google Apps granted me access to the App, but it gave me 403 on loading image. And it suddenly worked after I logged out my personal account. Not sure what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're trying to offer some sort of permalink from Google Drive that is publicly accessible.

- Open the File.
- Under the File Menu, Click Sharing.
- Under "Who has access", click Change.
  [image: private]
- Select "Public on the web".
  [image: sharing options]
- Click done, and copy the link listed.  That is your publicly available link which should work for you.
  [image: public link]

Comment: Nice! Thanks for the heads up (mistakes etc).

Comment: Actually i don't want to permalink to a view of the picture on google drive but actually ise that picture as an element of the html.

Answer (score 0):

You can embed your images using base 64 encoding.

```
function getFileBase64s(fileName) {
  var output = [];
  if (typeof fileName === 'string'){
    var fileIterator = DriveApp.getFilesByName(fileName);
    while (fileIterator.hasNext()) output.push(Utilities.base64Encode(fileIterator.next().getBlob().getBytes()));
  } else {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('File name: '+fileName+' is not an string')
  };
  return output;
};
```

In your HTML template:

```html
<? getFileBase64s('fileName').forEach(function(fileBase64){ ?>
    <img src="data:image/png;base64,<?=fileBase64?>" >
<? }) ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you access a file using the Advanced Drive Service, the metadata has an attribute called "thumbnailLink", which works well for displaying images in the Html Service, particularly if it is a file you do not want to share publicly. It is also much quicker than the base64 method. The link expires within hours, so you'll need to do a fresh request each time.

For a single image, the following will do the trick:

```js
Drive.Files.get(id).thumbnailLink
```

For several images, you can use the list method in the Advanced  Drive Service. For example, the following will access all images in a folder at the given id.

```js
  var query =  "'"+id+"' in parents and mimeType contains 'image/'"
  var files;
  var pageToken;
    do {
      files = Drive.Files.list({
        q: query,
        maxResults: 300,
        pageToken: pageToken
      });
      if (files.items && files.items.length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < files.items.length; i++) {
          var file = files.items[i];
          var title = file.title
          var src = file.thumbnailLink
        }
        
      }
      pageToken = files.nextPageToken;
    } while (pageToken);
```

You can also adjust the size of the image by replacing the "s220" string with a larger number, e.g., src = src.replace("s220","s1000").