# Serving images in an Apps Script through HtmlService

Tags: javascript, html, image, google-apps-script

Can anyone help me determine the best way to host and serve an image using GAS's HtmlService? I'm writing an app that needs a basic HTML UI with two small images, and I'm trying to keep everything as encapsulated as possible.

When I was prototyping on my local machine, I inserted the images inline as base64 encoded strings, but it looks like Caja does't support that.

I found this post about hosting images on Google Drive, which would work for my purposes, but apparently Drive recently deprecated that method:

[AppsScript- Using an image from Google Drive in HtmlService](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11249531/appsscript-using-an-image-from-google-drive-in-htmlservice)

I don't see any obvious way of doing this given the documentation, but I'd strongly prefer not to resort to hosting images on an external service.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/

Thanks for your insight!

Comment: Are you sure the  drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=<FILE_ID>; method is deprecated? Have you a source for this? It actually looks more like it was only relatively recent and appears to still be going strong.

Comment: I found a new things suggesting that it was deprecated since switching to the new Drive interface ([Source 1](https://support.google.com/richmedia/answer/6098968?hl=en), [Source 2](http://www.dalebasler.com/2014/03/get-a-direct-link-to-files-hosted-in-google-drive/)), but it appears to be working for me now using the instructions @Sandy posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that this way of displaying images uses drive hosting which will be discontinued August 31, 2016.

[Apps Developer Blog](http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.com/2015/08/deprecating-web-hosting-support-in.html)

You can save images to your Google drive, then use the `<img>` tag, and refer to the image in the source attribute:

For example:

```
<img src="https://googledrive.com/host/0B12wKjuEcjeiySkhPUTBsbW5j387M/my_image.png" height="95%" width="95%">
```

Note that you need to use:

```
"https://googledrive.com/host/[doc id]
```

where [doc id] is replaced by the document ID

[Google Documentation Link - Hosting](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2881970?hl=en)

Comment: Thanks! I tried this approach a number of times, but I must have had the permissions set wrong and/or I was using the wrong document ID. Nonetheless, it's working now.