# Google Apps Script - publish google documents and read urls

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm new to Google apps script.

I can create a number of documents in Google Drive via a script and add content.
I would also like to publish them via a script and record the published URL. Is this possible?

I can see an old answer from 2012
["Publish to the web" for Document in Google Apps Script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12275062/publish-to-the-web-for-document-in-google-apps-script)

Answer (score 0):

You can create all your content in a publicly shared folder, then once you have the folder's ID, you can create a straightforward base URL (e.g. `https://googledrive.com/host/[folder ID]/`) and simply append the newly created file names. I asked [a question related to this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27067095/serving-images-in-an-apps-script-through-htmlservice) a few days ago.

Conversely, you can [set the permissions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#setSharing(Access,Permission)) for each file you create then [get the download URL's](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getDownloadUrl()) for them individually using getDownloadUrl().